# Using os.walk to execute function on each subdirectory - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I am working on a project which uses os.walk to search subdirectories for individual jpg images and compile them in to a pdf document. I need to create one pdf document per subdirectory of the os.walk(search directory). The script I am currently working with combines every jpg found within the search directory in to one massive pdf. Is there a way to use os.walk to create a pdf for each subdirectory of the os.walk(search directory)?

Here is an example of the directory tree:

```
 <SearchDirectory>
   Roll 01
      frames
        001.jpg
        002.jpg
        003.jpg
   Roll 02
      frames
        001.jpg
        002.jpg
        003.jpg
   Roll 03
      frames
        001.jpg
        002.jpg
        003.jpg
```

Here is corrected script after feedback from abarnert:

```
 import os, sys, img2pdf

 if len(sys.argv) > 1:
     SearchDirectory = sys.argv[1]
     print ("I'm looking for JPGs in ", SearchDirectory)
 else:
     print ("Please tell me the directory to look in")
     sys.exit()

 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SearchDirectory):
     image_files = []
     for file in files:
         if ((os.path.basename(root)) == "frames") and (file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".JPG")):
             print("Discovered this jpg: ", os.path.join(root, file))
             image_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))

     if image_files:
         output_file = SearchDirectory + "\\" + (os.path.split(os.path.split(os.path.realpath(root))[0])[1]) + ".pdf"
         print ("Putting all JPGs into ", output_file)
         pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(image_files)
         file = open(output_file,"wb")
         file.write(pdf_bytes)
     else:
         print ("Couldn't find any JPGs")
```

Comment: Just move the `image_files = []` and the whole `if image_files:` block inside the outer `for … in os.walk…:` loop. The only other change you need to make is to create the `output_file` from the current position in the walk. That's it.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the image files per subdirectory then you should put the processing logic inside the `os.walk` loop. `image_files` should be re-initialized per loop as well:

```
import os, sys, img2pdf

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    SearchDirectory = sys.argv[1]
    print("I'm looking for JPGs in ", SearchDirectory)
else:
    print("Please tell me the directory to look in")
    sys.exit()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SearchDirectory):
    image_files = []
    for file in files:
        if ((os.path.basename(root)) == "frames") and (file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".JPG")):
            print("Discovered this jpg:", os.path.join(root, file))
            image_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    if image_files:
        output_file = SearchDirectory + "\\" + (os.path.split(os.path.split(os.path.realpath(root))[0])[1]) + ".pdf"
        print("Putting all JPGs into", output_file)
        pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(image_files)
        file = open(output_file, "wb")
        file.write(pdf_bytes)
    else:
        print("Couldn't find any JPGs in", root)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I believe this approach converts each individual jpg into a pdf. I am attempting to combine each jpg into a pdf per subdirectory.

Comment: @RBanks82 I see. In that case what abarnert mentioned is good indeed.